# copy rows between header and the last row

Tags: excel, vba

I found and modified a code that works pretty well but I am struggling with `Set CopyRng = sh.Range("A11:AI15")` . What I want to do is to create a dynamic range that will copy values from **first** table from each worksheet between header called *Language* and last row in table called *Total*. Some cells are merged in the table (default template) and there are empty columns in the table (so .CurrentRegion doesn't work).

```
Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
On Error Resume Next
LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function LastCol(sh As Worksheet)
On Error Resume Next
LastCol = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
Sub CopyRangeFromMultiWorksheets()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim DestSh As Worksheet
Dim Last As Long
Dim CopyRng As Range

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("test")

' Loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the
' summary worksheet.
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sh.Name Like "test*" Then

        Last = LastRow(DestSh)

        ' Specify the range to place the data.
        Set CopyRng = sh.Range("A11:AI15")

        CopyRng.Copy
        With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
            .PasteSpecial
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With

        DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A").Resize(CopyRng.Rows.Count).Value = sh.Range("F8")
        DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "AK").Resize(CopyRng.Rows.Count).Formula = "=AG10*3%"
        DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "AL").Resize(CopyRng.Rows.Count).Formula = "=AG10+AK10"

    End If
Next

ExitTheSub:

Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(1)

DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: I've tried to use CurrentRegion as well as End(xlToRight), End(xlDown) but nothing works because there are empty columns between columns with data so the macro just copies the first column. UsedRange also doesn't apply in this case because I just need to copy data from first table that is between Language Pair (header) and Total (last) rows. The header is always placed in the same row- row number 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that works great. See the code below:

```
Sub CopyRangeFromMultiWorksheets()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim DestSh As Worksheet
Dim Last As Long
Dim CopyRng As Range
Dim findrow As Long, findrow2 As Long

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set DestSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")


For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then

        Last = LastRow(DestSh)
        'this method doesn't work with merged cells thhat is why I have to unmerge them first.
        sh.Range("B10:B200").UnMerge
        findrow = sh.Range("B:B").Find("Language Pair", sh.Range("B1")).Row
        findrow2 = sh.Range("B:B").Find("Total", sh.Range("B" & findrow)).Row

        Set CopyRng = sh.Range("A" & findrow + 1 & ":AJ" & findrow2 - 1)

        CopyRng.Copy
        With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "B")
            .PasteSpecial
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With

        DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A").Resize(CopyRng.Rows.Count).Value = sh.Range("F8")
        DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "AK").Resize(CopyRng.Rows.Count).Formula = "=AG10*3%"
        DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "AL").Resize(CopyRng.Rows.Count).Formula = "=AG10+AK10"

    End If
Next

ExitTheSub:

Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(1)

DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub

Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
On Error Resume Next
LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function LastCol(sh As Worksheet)
On Error Resume Next
LastCol = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will return you the range. Parameters explained:

- `oW` = The worksheet you want to get the range from
- `sStartColHeader` = Holds the name of the header column you want to start the range from (i.e. in your example this would be "**Language**")

  ```
  Function GetRange(ByVal oW As Worksheet, ByVal sStartColHeader As String) As Range
      Dim oTotRng As Range: Set oTotRng = oW.Cells.Find("total", oW.Cells(1, 1), xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, xlNext, False, , False)
      Dim oLan As Range

      Set oLan = oW.Cells.Find(sStartColHeader, oW.Cells(1, 1), xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, xlNext, False, , False)
      If oLan Is Nothing Then
          Set GetRange = Nothing
      Else
          Set GetRange = Range(oLan.Offset(1, 0), oTotRng.Offset(0, 1))
      End If

  End Function
  ```

**How to use this function**:
In `CopyRangeFromMultiWorksheets` function, change `Set CopyRng = sh.Range("A11:AI15")` to `Set CopyRng = GetRange(sh, "Language")`. Then have an `If` condition to check if a range was returned. For example:

```
Set CopyRng = GetRange(sh, "Language")
If CopyRng Is Nothing Then
    ' your exception code here as range was not returned
Else
    ' rest of your code here as a range was returned
End If
```

**NOTE**: Presumption is that the actual total amount in the sheet is in the cell to the right of the cell that contains the text **`Total`**. So if "**`H10`**" has text **`Total`**, actual total is held in cell "**`I10`**"

Comment: it works but not in the way I wish to. The problem is that Language is one of the header name. I forgot to mention that the last column is always AJ, the copy range always starts from A11 and the destination range starts from A10 cell. I tried to put  `sh.Range("A11:AJ" & LastRow)` but it still doesn't copy everything I want. I also know that the rows I am looking for contains FR* and EN*. I hope that it is clear.